# SQL Oracle (group by)

Tags: oracle, group-by

This is my output.

```
Name         Start      End
------      --------    --------
Mary        09-04-01    10-04-30
John        08-05-25    11-07-24
Alisa       07-07-07    11-06-28
Mary        06-06-06    12-12-20
John        05-05-05    12-12-20
Alex        04-04-04    11-12-20
Alisa       03-03-03    13-12-20
Mary        09-04-04    13-12-21
John        08-06-06    13-04-30
John        08-06-01    14-04-30
```

I need to `GROUP BY` every name, get the `MIN() START` for each person and get the `MAX() END`. Then, the difference between the `START` and the `END` like this :

```
Name         Start      End         Difference
-------     --------    --------    ----------
Mary        06-06-06    13-12-21    MONTHS_BETWEEN(start,end)
John        05-05-05    14-04-30    MONTHS_BETWEEN(start,end)
Alisa       03-03-03    13-12-20    MONTHS_BETWEEN(start,end)
Alex        04-04-04    11-12-20    MONTHS_BETWEEN(start,end)
```

This is my query. I'm only able to get this result, I don't know why I can't GROUP BY everyname. It seems to be working correctly for the `difference`. I exclude the `FROM`.

```
SELECT table.name, MIN(tableDate.Start), MAX(tableDate.end), 
Round(MONTHS_BETWEEN(tableDate.end, tableDate.Start),0) as Difference
FROM (....)
GROUP BY table.name,tableDate.Start, tableDate.End
;
```

If I remove `table.Date.Start` and `tableDate.End` from the `GROUP BY`, Oracle is given me the error :

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

tableDate.Start and tableDate.End are calculated columns so i dont know why i've to put them in the GROUP BY clause.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you do need to group by the `name` column only. But one issue with your query is that the months between calculation needs to be using the `MAX` and `MIN` values. You are also using some reserved words as column names:

```
SELECT  T.name, 
        MIN(T.Start) AS Start, 
        MAX(T."end") AS "End",
        ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(MAX(T."end"),MIN(T.Start)),0) as "Difference"
FROM YourTable T
GROUP BY T.name;
```

Comment: It works PERFECTLY. Thanks a lot ! I didn't think to make the calculation within the function.

Answer (score 0):

All non-aggregates need to be in the Grouping, and `Round(MONTHS_BETWEEN....` doesn't introduce `tableDate.Start` and `tableDate.End` with an aggregate. Depending on the interpretation of the data, it seems you want to use the already calculated `MIN` and `MAX` values in the `MONTHS_BETWEEN` calculation. How about this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT table.name, MIN(tableDate.Start) AS MinStart, MAX(tableDate.end) as MaxEnd
  FROM (....)
  GROUP BY table.name
)
SELECT name, MinStart, MaxEnd, Round(MONTHS_BETWEEN(MaxEnd, MinStart),0) as Difference
FROM cte;
```